# How can I set onAnimationEnd() in Rebound(Spring_Facebook)

Tags: android, facebook, android-animation

I am trying to use [Rebound](http://facebook.github.io/rebound/) and [Backboard](https://github.com/tumblr/Backboard) in my app for beauty.

I want to know how to set functions after Spring Animation is done.

Below is example code. (Original code is [this](https://github.com/tumblr/Backboard/blob/master/backboard-example/src/main/java/com/tumblr/backboard/example/BloomFragment.java) one. and I add some codes for holding blooming animation)

```
// mRootView.setOnTouchListener(new ToggleImitator(spring, CLOSED, OPEN));
// Instead of ToggleImitator, I made below codes for holding spring animation.
mRootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mySpring.getEndValue() == OPEN) {
                mySpring.setEndValue(CLOSED);
                Log.d("SpringValue", String.valueOf(mySpring.getEndValue()));
            } else {
                mySpring.setEndValue(OPEN);
                Log.d("SpringValue", String.valueOf(mySpring.getEndValue()));
            }
        }
    });
```

But, what I really want to know is getting Listener whether spring animation is over. (for adding Logs, changing circle's color, or something else which is really important to performing app)

I already used `spring.addListener(SimpleSpringListener listener)` like below code.

```
mySpring.addListener(new SimpleSpringListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSpringActivate(Spring spring) {
                super.onSpringActivate(spring);
                if (spring.getCurrentValue() == spring.getEndValue()) {
                    Log.d("Spring State", "END");
                }
            }
});
```

But, not working at all.... :(

Please help me!!

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @TusharGogna Maybe I solved (or bypass) this problem, but it's been too long to remember :(